# How can i know that the Stream is end?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I am using serialization to write with Append some contacts with their name and phone to a file, I am writing each contact alone by append it to the file.

I want to read these contacts from the file and put them in a ListView.

```
Stream stream = File.Open("Contacts.dat", FileMode.Open);
BinaryFormatter BFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Contacts contact = (Contacts)BFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "", contact.name, contact.phone }));
```

After I am doing the above code I get only one contact and if I deserialize the stream again i get the next contact

```
Contacts contact2 = (Contacts)BFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "", contact2.name, contact2.phone}));
```

How can I read all the contacts?
or how can I know that the stream is end?

Comment: i suggest to look in documentation of your BFormatter class. This class is not part of .net

Comment: why is his own class relevant to the question?

Comment: It's related because of the way the Deserialize method gets data from the stream. That should tell him how he needs to exit a loop that will get all the contact from the stream.

Comment: Consider serializing an array or List<> instead.  If that's not suitable then you'll have to detect end-of-file from the stream properties.

Comment: List<> doesn't work ... May be because i append the serialized contacts each time ... then the header of the serialization is added every time in the new contact ... I am not sure
But i tried it and get an error "Unable to cast"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the stream `Position` property against stream `Length` property, assuming your are refering to file stream

Comment: But when i opened the file, I can see the data?!! 
I don't want the user to be able to read the data ... how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which kind of stream it is. For instance, a `NetworkStream` will never end (since TCP is stream based). A `FileStream` will end when `Read` returns 0 bytes.

Comment: StreamReader has it's own Method StreamReader.EndOfStream();

Comment: @Cody: Which is just a wrapper around the stream and uses the stream to detect the end.

Comment: No i can't use StreamReader in serialization.. can i?